# "Исправимая фатальная ошибка: объект класса mysqli не может быть преобразован в строку в" Ошибка в запросе

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

function get_post_by_id($post_id){
        global $link;

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id =".$post_id;

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result,1);

    return $post;
  }
```

Comment: вы уверены, что ошибка в этом коде? на какую строку ругается? что такое 1 в fetch?

Comment: на второй строке, где я вызываю запрос

Comment: @splash58 Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\hw-17\base\products.php on line 24